# Ion-auth not logging in after registering.

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I just installed the ion-auth library and I'm trying to do some basic operations with it, including registering and logging in. Registering works just fine (I can see the row has been added to the database), but trying to login with the same credentials as I used to create the user with doesn't work for some reason.

This is the basic flow:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $additional_data = array(
            'first name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe'
        );

        $this->ion_auth->register($username,$password,$email,$additional_data);
        $this->ion_auth->login($username, $password, TRUE);
```

But for whatever reason, the login mechanism simply won't work. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had he struggle that i could not login with ion_auth, i could only login with the admin credentials.
For me the answer was simple but very specific. It may not answer the question for you, but it just might.

I had a redirect from the login to the dashboard controller. Only the dashboard controller was only viewable by an admin. If the user wasn't an admin, it was redirected to the login page.

Therefore it looked like the user was not logged in, but he was.

Comment: I just got around to testing what you said - only being able to login with admin credentials. That would seem to be the problem.

Comment: Okay I have no idea what happened but the code which didn't work for 3 hours now works without me altering it. So yeah...

Comment: maybe do a clean install of codeigniter and ion_auth? or did you already have a whole app around it? you probably did touch something, otherwise this cannot happen

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, doing a clean install. Thanks for your help anyway.